# Multiple images UITable view

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have my images row by row. I want to load the images in my table view like

http://pinterest.com/

Is it possible or we want to use some other view to achive this?

Comment: I would investigate UICollectionView in iOS 6 in order to produce something similar to this although this should be possible with a scrollview.  Apple had some WWDC 2012 videos where they showed the flexibility of UICollectionView. See https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use BDDynamicGridViewController for iOS

Data-aware view controller that displays a UIView list (typically, UIImageView list) in a row-dominated grid layout. This class automatically lay out the UIViews with help from a delegate class (which is supplied by you). 
You can find it [here](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/bddynamicgridviewcontroller).Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Also see the [JSPintDemo](https://github.com/jayslu/JSPintDemo) layout for UICollectionView.

[image]